# How to call Fragment method from an another fragment in android

Tags: java, performance, android-studio, android-fragments, fragment

I want to call A class fragment method in B class Fragment what is the best approach. I already saw many different approach but every time app getting crash

```
 public class **AFragment** extends Fragment {
        
      static AFragment instance=null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        instance = this;
        
    }
        public void followUnfollowUser() {
        
         //My main code is here
        
        }

      public static AFragment getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
 
        
        public class **BFragment** extends Fragment {
        
        public void call_A_method() {
        
        AFragment.getInstance().followUnfollowUser();
        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sharedViewModel. like if you want to update the followunfollow button in fragment A after doing any followunfollow event in Fragment B.